# Google Analytics not displaying goal conversion

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

[image]

I have created a goal  when i click verify it shows conversion rate, but Analytics shows me 0% conversions for the past 7 days.
Why is it so..?

Comment: If you just created it, there are no metrics yet. It can take some time.

Answer (score 2):

The predicted goal conversion rate (ie. 0.78% in your case) is an estimate of the rate of conversion if your configuration were to be applied to past data, which of course it will not do. Also, data processing of goal conversion (and all GA) data takes some time, usually up to 24 hours, so your reports will still show 0 until the data has been processed.